# Which one is better structure for FK relation deletion in django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
class Address(models.Model):
    old_address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    new_address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    bjdongName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ...
```

```
1. 
class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    address = models.OneToOneField(Address, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="listing")

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        address = self.address
        super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
        address.delete()
```

```
2. 
class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class ListingAddress(Address):
    listing = models.OneToOneField(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Q1. Which structure is better ?

Q2. If I want to delete OneToOneField parent, override delete method or using signal post_delete.
But are those performances same? Only when I need to delete_bulk, I need to use signal? Is there another reason using signal delete?

Answer (score 0):

You should not extends the delete method to delete a parent object, Django provide an emulation for the behavior of the SQL constraint specified by the on_delete argument.

For a performance perspective Django says : **Note that the delete() method for an object is not necessarily called when deleting objects in bulk using a QuerySet or as a result of a cascading delete.**

So by setting on_delete to CASCADE you are telling Django to emulates the behavior of the SQL at DB level, so it should not only perform better but avoid common mistake or the the object not deleting.

[on_delete Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete)

Comment: Then you think next way it better?
Then If I have ```class Housing(models.Model): address = ...``` I need to implement one more ```class HousingAddress extends Address``` Does it make sense? Everytime I need to implement new type of address?

Comment: The first one is wrong, you are setting to NULL and finally you make an extra request to your DB to delete the object.
Don't forget as well that in Django explicit is better.